# finding an element in json using get_json_object or json_tuple in hql

Tags: json, hadoop, hql

Below is the sample json element in my table. i want to only get typ SSN and typ TIN and their respective Id's in my output. I am using below code but i am traversing manually to each iteration and getting all the typ one by one which i want to avoid, instead go through each element and get me only typ as SSN or TIN

select get_json_object(get_json_object(b.gov_doc_id, '$.[0]') ,'$.typ')),'') as char(15)) as idtyp1

'''
[{"lst_updt_src":"yyyyyyy","processed":{"typ":"SSN","id":"XXXXXXXXX","std_ind":"Y"},"issue_ctry_cd":"CC","typ":"SSN","id":" XXXXXXXXX ","lst_updt_ts":"2015-09-21T12:16:43.587610","id_last4":"XXXX"}, {"lst_updt_src":"xxxxxx","processed":{"typ":"DRIVERSLICENSE","id":"XXXXXXXXX","std_ind":"Y"},"typ":"DRIVERS_LICENSE","id":" XXXXXXXXX ","lst_updt_ts":"2015-09-21T12:16:43.587710","id_last4":"XXXX"}, {"lst_updt_src":"xxxxxx","processed":{"typ":"TIN","id":"XXXXXXXXX","std_ind":"Y"},"typ":"TIN","id":"XXXXXXXXX ","lst_updt_ts":"2015-09-21T12:16:43.587689","id_last4":"XXXX"}]
'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `select get_json_object(gov_doc_id, '$[*].typ') idtyp1`